# Rails image and tracking protection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I have made a sample app with devise and facebook auth. I want to show fb profile photo as the user's avatar and it's working in chrome and IE. But in firefox I see the warning about 'Tracking Protection' - 'Connection is not secure'.

I wrote a simple method:

```
def avatar_for(user)
  avatar_url = user.image
  image_tag(avatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "avatar") unless user.image.nil?
end
```

How can I make such a method/connection safe?

> EDIT: It's exactly how max wrote: using https address vis
>   secure_image_url   removes the warning in 'Tracking Protection'
>   warning in Firefox, but no image is displayed.

Comment: You should retrieve the image via `https`

Comment: It sounds pretty obvious but: facebook give in callback address in http i could change  it manually to https and it would works but firefox although doesn't display image, this time without warning

Answer (score 6):

Use the `secure_image_url` option to have OmniAuth Facebook create a HTTPS address instead:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'],
    secure_image_url: true
end
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are using OmniAuth Facebook. Please tell me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Yes I'm using OmniAuth. I have set up the OmniAuth to use secure_image_url and now new account are created with https link to profil image but firefox still didn't shows it

Comment: Ah I haven't encountered it yet - but it seems like the could be due to Moz new [Tracking Protection feature which seems to dodge images which it deems are used to track user traffic](https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2014/11/12/quantifying-the-effects-of-firefoxs-tracking-protection/). Unfortunatly I don't quite know what to do about it. You could download the image when creating the profile but that might violate the facebook TOS.

Comment: Thanks for the try, I'll keep looking further . Hopefully i would find the correct answer ;)

Comment: Good luck! If I got this straight using a `https` address removes the warning   in `'Tracking Protection'` warning in Firefox, but no image is displayed? Can you edit the question to reflect this and I'll put a bounty on it.